# different ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush behaviour with embedded vs ng-content children

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I am tweaking the performance of the application and came across following differences. Please see [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yruvic) for the live example.

Components with the suffix `-on-push` have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, whereas components with the suffix `-default` have the default strategy.

I have two approaches which i named "embedded" for the first, and "ng-content" for the second. The clarification follows below.

root template:

```
<h1>embedded</h1>
<app-embedded-on-push></app-embedded-on-push>

<h1>ng-content</h1>
<app-ng-content-on-push>
  <app-ng-content-default></app-ng-content-default>
</app-ng-content-on-push>
```

Where `app-embedded-on-push`s template just "embeds" the `app-embedded-default` component:

```
<app-embedded-default></app-embedded-default>
```

On the other hand, `app-ng-content-on-push`s template projects the `app-ng-content-default` component with `ng-content`:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Please see the stackblitz in order to get a better idea.

## expectation

Since components with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` are only being checked (the component itself and its children) if the input references have changed, my expectation is that on the component itself and its children, the change detection **won't** be triggered with both approaches, named the embedded and the content-projection approach.

## reality

With the embedded approach, the behaviour is as expected, change detection on `app-embedded-default` won't be triggered.
On the other hand, with content projection (`ng-content`), the change detection of the child component of `app-ng-content-on-push` **is being** triggered, as you can see on the above stackblitz.

Can someone explain why this is the outcoming behaviour? The component tree is the same on both approaches, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reality is correct because if we take a look at the template:

```
<app-ng-content-on-push>
  <app-ng-content-default></app-ng-content-default>
</app-ng-content-on-push>
```

we can't say that `app-ng-content-default` is the child component of `app-ng-content-on-push` but rather this component is projected into `app-ng-content-on-push`.

This means that this component is a part of AppComponent template and will be checked when AppComponent template is checked. `app-ng-content-on-push` won't protect `app-ng-content-default` from checking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What are the alternatives? Detaching the ChangeDetector and triggering the changes manually, I guess? Is there any official documentation that covers that use case regarding change detection?

Comment: You're on the right direction. Detaching change detector or using OnPush on that projected component will work for you. I didn't see any official documentation regarding how Angular Change Detection works under the hood. There is not official article with deep explaining how it works under the hood https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-change-detection-strategies-in-angular-d4ca7744085a.

Comment: You could try wrapping that projectable content in ng-template but it will also not work since Angular will mark projected content for check. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L358